# Generate struct in matlab with fields of different sizes

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to generate a collection of information about a set of images, so I've created a struct array as follow,

```
resultsInfo = struct('img_index',0,'correlated',cell(1,5),'correlationFactor',zeros(1,5),'ImgSum',zeros(640,480));
```

Where: `img_index` is an integer that represents the image, the `correlated` is the cells containing the name of correlated images, `correlationFactor` is a number which represents how the images are similar, and the `imgSum` is a sum of correlated images.

I want to create the array in a dynamic way, inside a for loop, but the code generates only the fifth `imageSums` of each element.

How can I start the struct to fill all the elements of the array with the matrix of zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please define following method :

```
function resultStruct = CreateEmptySruct ()
    resultStruct.img_index = 0  ;
    resultStruct.correlated  = cell(1,5);
    resultStruct.correlationFactor = zeros(1,5);
    resultStruct.ImgSum = zeros(640,480) ;
end
```

Then call this method in For loop like this:

```
for i = 1 :5
    structArray(i) = CreateEmptySruct () ;
end
```

However, you can also set any value to each struct individually by passing function arguments.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. If this solution worked for you then please accept the answer.